# Formatting ExtJS grid column

Tags: formatting, extjs4.1, extjs-grid

I know I can format an ExtJs grid's column by using [Ext.Util.Format](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.util.Format) class.
I want to know how can I apply following format types:

1. Showing percent symbol for a number without multiplying it by 100. So If the value is 10.34 it should show 10.34% and now 1034%.
2. If the number is negative it should be shown in red color insde brackets. so -23 should be shown in red color as (23).

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I would have liked to have some more details :

- Do you want to apply both renderings to a single column?
- Could you provide a concise code sample of what you have already tried (store/model bound to the grid panel, raw data to feed the store, column configuration(s))?

Anyway, I can give it a try (you should [read the doc](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-cfg-renderer) first).

Renderer 1 :

```
renderer: function (value) {
    return value + '%';
}
```

Renderer 2 :

```
renderer: function (value) {
    return value < 0 
        ? '<span style="color:red">(' + Math.abs(value) + ')</span>' 
        : value;
}
```

Frankenstein's monster :

```
renderer: function (value) {
    return value < 0 
        ? '<span style="color:red">(' + Math.abs(value) + '%)</span>' 
        : value + '%';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can achieve through `renderer` concept, please refer below sample for your queries.

```
  {
       text     : 'Number (Percentage)',
       width    : 80,
       sortable : true,
       renderer :  function(val) {
           if (val > 0) {
              return '<span style="color:green;">' + val + '</span>';
           } else if (val < 0) {
              return '<span style="color:red;">' + val + '</span>';
           }
           return val+"%";
       },
       dataIndex: 'numberChange' // place your dataindex binding here
    }
```

Thanks, Hope this will help you...

Answer (score 0):

You could easily implement a [renderer](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-cfg-renderer) for the columns, and transform the results however you'd like. All you have to do is return the transformed string from the renderer; plus, you have access to the full `Ext.data.Record` for the grid row (as well as the store, for that matter), so you can also easily do custom renderings based on other data within the record, if needed.